# Woocommerce product notes add to order meta

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I created textarea field to save woocommerce products notes, i want to save these notes into admin order if any product available in cart and have product notes.

```html
// WooCommerce Products Custom Field
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields' );
function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {
  global $woocommerce, $post;
  echo '<div class="options_group">';
  // Textarea Field
 woocommerce_wp_textarea_input( 
  array( 
   'id'          => 'product_notes', 
   'label'       => __( 'Product Notes', 'woocommerce' ), 
   'placeholder' => 'Enter product notes here.',
   'desc_tip'    => 'true',
   'description' => __( 'Enter product notes here.', 'woocommerce' ) 
  )
 );
  echo '</div>'; 
}
// Save Product notes
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );
function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){
 // Textarea
 $woocommerce_textarea = $_POST['product_notes'];
 if( !empty( $woocommerce_textarea ) )
  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'product_notes', esc_html( $woocommerce_textarea ) );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i find solution.

```html
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_product_notes_order_meta', 10, 2 );

function custom_product_notes_order_meta( $order_id ) {
 global $woocommerce;
 $i=1; //product counter
 foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
     $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];     
     $product_note = 'product_notes_'.$i++;
     if( !empty(get_post_meta( $product_id, 'product_notes', true )) ){
      $product_notes = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'product_notes', true );
      add_post_meta( $order_id, $product_note, $product_notes );
     }
    }
}
```